# How to cycle across 2 forloops within a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django template where I need to cycle through a set of background colours across two different for loops. The cycle tag seems to be designed to be used either within one for loop or outside a for loop altogether. This is my code:

```
{% if global_adverts %}
        <span style="display:none">{% cycle 'advert-grey' 'advert-pale-blue' 'advert-green' 'advert-blue' as adcolors %}</span>
        {% for advert in global_adverts %}
            <div class="{% cycle adcolors %}">
                {% if advert.url %}<a href="{{ advert.url }}">{% endif %}
                    <p>{{ advert.text }}</p>
                {% if advert.url %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% with self.adverts.all as adverts %}
        {% if adverts %}
            {% for advert in adverts %}
                <div class="{% cycle adcolors %}">
                    {% if advert.url %}<a href="{{ advert.url }}">{% endif %}
                        <p>{{ advert.text }}</p>
                    {% if advert.url %}</a>{% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

Is there a way to do this without outputting the first item in the cycle before the first loop and having to hide it with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that the following code gives the desired result:

```
{% if global_adverts %}
        {% for advert in global_adverts %}
            <div class="{% cycle 'advert-grey' 'advert-pale-blue' 'advert-green' 'advert-blue' as adcolours %}">
                {% if advert.url %}<a href="{{ advert.url }}">{% endif %}
                    <p>{{ advert.text }}</p>
                {% if advert.url %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% with self.adverts.all as adverts %}
        {% if adverts %}
            {% for advert in adverts %}
                <div class="{% cycle adcolours %}">
                    {% if advert.url %}<a href="{{ advert.url }}">{% endif %}
                        <p>{{ advert.text }}</p>
                    {% if advert.url %}</a>{% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add **silent**

```
{% cycle 'advert-grey' 'advert-pale-blue' 'advert-green' 'advert-blue' as adcolors silent %}
```

It prevents the tag from outputting the value

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

If you need the cycle to continue for each loop just use cycle twice and change the order of the items in the second cycle:

```
{% if global_adverts %}
        {% for advert in global_adverts %}
            <div class="{% cycle 'advert-grey' 'advert-pale-blue' 'advert-green' 'advert-blue' %}">
                {% if advert.url %}<a href="{{ advert.url }}">{% endif %}
                    <p>{{ advert.text }}</p>
                {% if advert.url %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% with self.adverts.all as adverts %}
        {% if adverts %}
            {% for advert in adverts %}
                <div class="{% cycle 'advert-pale-blue' 'advert-green' 'advert-blue' 'advert-grey' %}">
                    {% if advert.url %}<a href="{{ advert.url }}">{% endif %}
                        <p>{{ advert.text }}</p>
                    {% if advert.url %}</a>{% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

Comment: That seems to suppress the output at every point I call it, not just the first time.

Comment: Yes now i see the exact use you do with cycle, which is a bit odd, I'll check for a solution

Comment: @Brighty so you just want the cycle items to be the same in each loop iteration?

Comment: I need the cycle to continue across the two for loops. In an ideal world I'd set a counter variable before the first loop, and then increment it through each cycle of both loops. But obviously I can't do that in a django template.

Comment: Thanks - but that isn't quite right either. The problem with the code above is that it starts the cycle again for the second loop, rather than continuing through the list of background colours.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that having the first `{% cycle %}` declaration outside of the loops is cleaner, I wouldn't have expected a declaration inside of *conditional* loops to work, and here's how to make it work:

```
{% cycle 'advert-grey' 'advert-pale-blue' 'advert-green' 'advert-blue' as adcolour silent %}

{% if global_adverts %}
    {% for advert in global_adverts %}
        <div class="{{ adcolours }}">
            {% if advert.url %}<a href="{{ advert.url }}">{% endif %}
                <p>{{ advert.text }}</p>
            {% if advert.url %}</a>{% endif %}
        </div>
        {% cycle adcolours %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% with self.adverts.all as adverts %}
    {% if adverts %}
        {% for advert in adverts %}
            <div class="{{ adcolours }}">
                {% if advert.url %}<a href="{{ advert.url }}">{% endif %}
                    <p>{{ advert.text }}</p>
                {% if advert.url %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
            {% cycle adcolour %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Since `{% cycle adcolour %}` is silent, we use `{{ adcolour }}` to print the current colour. We still need to use the silent `{% cycle adcolour %}` to step through the colours on each iteration.